# del self followed by super() call raises RuntimeError

Tags: python, inheritance, garbage-collection

I was playing around with inheritance today, and I came across this exception:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       del self
       super().__init__(**locals())

A()  # RuntimeError: super(): arg[0] deleted
```

Why does this happen? If I replace the line with `super().__init__(**{})` and remove the deletion of self it works just fine.
I was under the impression that `self` in this case is only a reference to the instance, so why does deleting it break the super reference?

Comment: I got the same error with `**{}`

Comment: I should've specified I also removed `del self`.

Comment: `super()` is a _kind_ of short form for `super(A, self)`, [see](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=super#invocation-from-super)

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the self object is ending up deleted. I thought it was just a reference. Is garbage collection getting triggered between the del and the super() call? Or is super() implemented so that it calls the self inside the function rather than what self is pointing at, but finds it as a deleted variable and so can't use it?

Comment: @SomeGuy With `del self` you're removing `self` from the local dictionary/ scope making it unavailable to `super`.

Comment: @SomeGuy `self` is just a normal object that you could delete but shouldn't which gets created by `object.__new__`. It breaks the code because `super` needs `self` and can't find it.